# Form $validators without ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a `form` element:

```
<form name="formDate">
    <input date-picker name="fundacao" ng-model-date="fTit.fundacao" required>
</form>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModelDate: "=ngModelDate"
        },
        link: function (ng, el, attr) {     
            // $validators HERE
        }
    };
})
```

The "required" validation does not work because there is no `ng-model` directive on the element.

Is there any way to validate a form with nonstandard directives, such as the example above?

Comment: It is actually quite possible just to use ngModel by requireing it in your directive. That way validators in general can be used, ofc. the specific validator have to make sense for the given time. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0):

you can bind change function on element

```
app.directive('datePicker', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        ngModelDate: "=ngModelDate"
    },
    link: function (ng, el, attr,ctrl) {     
        el.bind('change',function(){
          //check the $(el).val();
         var isValid= the date is valid;
         ctrl.$setValidity('date',isValid);
         // the first param is the validation key, the second param is true if valid false if invalid
    })
   }
 };
})
```

Comment: Ok, how do I change the validity of the form ($scope.formDate)? Before submitting the form, I need to read the property $scope.formDate.$valid.

Comment: ctrl in this case is undefined. This really works if there is a "require: ngModel". However, the "require: ngModelDate" also not work either.